# Can I execute a dynamic sql statement in an after update trigger?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, dynamic-sql

I am using the following statement:

```
query_str='SELECT :NEW.FIRST_NAME||:NEW.LAST_NAME INTO  HostID 
FROM INPUT_TABLE WHERE INPUT_ID='
```

The trigger has the following code:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query_str ||:NEW.INPUT_ID;
```

I'm getting the following error when updating INPUT_TABLE:
  ORA-01008: not all variables bound

If I'm updating a record where input_id=111, I would think Oracle would just execute the following statement:

```
SELECT :NEW.FIRST_NAME||:NEW.LAST_NAME INTO  HostID 
FROM INPUT_TABLE WHERE INPUT_ID=111
```

Why is it having binding issues?

I'm using SQLDeveloper.

```
create or replace   
TRIGGER DATA_DETAIL_TRIG
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
ON INPUT_TABLE
FOR EACH ROW
 DECLARE
   DATA_SOURCE_ID_RET  NUMBER;
   resultcount        NUMBER;
   query_str          VARCHAR2(512);
   using_cl          VARCHAR2(512);
   HostId      VARCHAR2(256);
   DATA_SOURCE_ID       NUMBER;
   INPUT_ID         NUMBER(38,0);
   AUTOGENERATE_IND       VARCHAR2(1);
   autogen_const varchar(200);
   pragma autonomous_transaction;
   CURSOR C_DATA_SOURCES IS 
    SELECT DATA_SOURCE_ID
    FROM DATA_SOURCE_DETAIL
    WHERE AUTOGENERATE_IND='Y'
    AND DATA_SOURCE_REF.ACTIVE_IND='Y';
BEGIN


OPEN C_DATA_SOURCES;
LOOP
  FETCH C_DATA_SOURCES INTO DATA_SOURCE_ID_RET;
  EXIT WHEN C_DATA_SOURCES%NOTFOUND;
    query_str:=getHostQuery( DATA_SOURCE_ID_RET);
--SELECT :FIRST_NAME||:LAST_NAME||to_char(:DOB,'yyyy/mm/dd')    
From INPUT_TABLE WHERE     INPUT_ID=:INPUT_ID
using_cl:=getHostUsing(DATA_SOURCE_ID_RET);
--:NEW.FIRST_NAME, :NEW.LAST_NAME, :NEW.DOB, :NEW.INPUT_ID
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query_str  INTO HostId USING using_cl;

  IF INSERTING THEN
    INSERT INTO DETAIL_TABLE
  (
  DETAIL_ID,
  INPUT_ID,
  HOST_ID,
  DATA_SOURCE_ID,
  NOTE,
  DATE_MODIFIED
  ) VALUES
  (
   DETAIL_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
    :NEW.INPUT_ID,
    HostId,
    DATA_SOURCE_ID_RET,
    'Autogenerate Data Source Insert for Insert Input',
    SYSDATE
  );

ELSIF UPDATING THEN



SELECT COUNT(DATA_SOURCE_ID) INTO resultcount FROM DETAIL_TABLE WHERE     
INPUT_ID=:NEW.INPUT_ID AND DATA_SOURCE_ID=DATA_SOURCE_ID_RET;
  IF resultcount>0 THEN


    UPDATE DETAIL_TABLE
    SET
  HOST_ID = HostId,
  NOTE ='Autogenerate Data Source Update for Update Input',
  DATE_MODIFIED =SYSDATE
  WHERE INPUT_ID=:NEW.INPUT_ID
  AND DATA_SOURCE_ID=DATA_SOURCE_ID_RET;


  ELSE
      INSERT INTO DETAIL_TABLE
  (
  DETAIL_ID,
  INPUT_ID,
  HOST_ID,
  DATA_SOURCE_ID,
  NOTE,
  DATE_MODIFIED
  ) VALUES
  (
  DETAIL_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
  :NEW.INPUT_ID,
  HostId,
   DATA_SOURCE_ID_RET,
   'Autogenerate Data Source Insert for Update Input ',

    SYSDATE
  );
END IF;
--end if insert or update inside update

END IF;
--end IF UPDATING
END LOOP;
Close C_DATA_SOURCES;

COMMIT;
END DATA_DETAIL_TRIG;
--end trigger
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you you placed your `:new` variables in quotes, Oracle looses their meaning as special trigger variables and interprets them as regular bind variables. You probably need to use `USING` clause with your dynamic sql. Something like

```
query_str:='SELECT :FIRST_NAME||:LAST_NAME
 FROM INPUT_TABLE WHERE INPUT_ID=:ID';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query_str INTO HostID USING 
  :NEW.FIRST_NAME,:NEW.LAST_NAME,:NEW.INPUT_ID;
```

---

Update.

Now as more details emerge, I wonder why do you need to query at all? From what I can see, you just compose `HostID` from some values in `INPUT_TABLE`. But since you already have have trigger attached to the same table, you already have all values you need and can simply do

```
HostID := :NEW.FIRST_NAME||:NEW.LAST_NAME;
```

Your approach would only make sense if you query different table. In this case, as I mentioned, you can't quote `:NEW` or `:OLD` when you place them in `USING`. You may compose other value from them, though.

Comment: Thank you so much! The instructions in query_str will change.  Sometimes it might have SSN, DOB, etc.  Could I pass in the whole row in the using clause, or should using only contain the specific variable? I wouldn't be able to create the using clause dynamically, either--it would still have the :NEW keyword in quotes.

Comment: `USING` just binds the variable. But you can construct specific text before query and pass it. Like `str:=:new.ssn||.:new.dob` and then call it with `USING str`.

Comment: It looks like this is working, but it says "not all variables are bound":
ORA-01008: not all variables bound
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
SELECT :FIRST_NAME||:LAST_NAME||:DOB FROM INPUT WHERE INPUT_ID=:INPUT_ID
INTO HostID 
USING
:NEW.FIRST_NAME, :NEW.LAST_NAME, NEW:DOB, :NEW.PATIENT_ID;

Comment: @JeanneLane - are you using a `qry_str` variable to hold the statement, or running it directly? If the latter, do you have single quotes around the statement? `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ... ' INTO HostID USING ...`

Comment: I'm using athe query_str and using_cl variables  to hold parts of the statement.

Comment: I tested the answer I gave. Provide exact copy of the sql that you use and I can take a look.

Comment: You can't use some string for `using` clause. You need to have exactly as many real arguments and you have bind variables. I see what your problem is. I'll think of a good way to solve it. In the meantime, please copy your sql to main question and delete your answer.

Comment: Actually, it's very simple. In getHostQuery just compose response directly: `select first_name||last_name from input_table where input_id=:id`. The call it with `using DATA_SOURCE_ID_RET`. I assume that first_name, last_name etc are fixed columns in the table, right?

Comment: Yes, the column names are fixed. If first_name has been changed, the new value will be selected without the :NEW keyword?

Comment: I added update to the answer. I don't think you even need a query! However, if you really want to do it - yes just use column name and you will get the value from the table. No need for :NEW.

Answer (score 0):

@Alex: Below is the trigger.

```
create or replace   
TRIGGER DATA_DETAIL_TRIG
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
ON INPUT_TABLE
FOR EACH ROW
 DECLARE
   DATA_SOURCE_ID_RET  NUMBER;
   resultcount        NUMBER;
   query_str          VARCHAR2(512);
   using_cl          VARCHAR2(512);
   HostId      VARCHAR2(256);
   DATA_SOURCE_ID       NUMBER;
   INPUT_ID         NUMBER(38,0);
   AUTOGENERATE_IND       VARCHAR2(1);
   autogen_const varchar(200);
   pragma autonomous_transaction;
   CURSOR C_DATA_SOURCES IS 
    SELECT DATA_SOURCE_ID
    FROM DATA_SOURCE_DETAIL
    WHERE AUTOGENERATE_IND='Y'
    AND DATA_SOURCE_REF.ACTIVE_IND='Y';
BEGIN


OPEN C_DATA_SOURCES;
LOOP
  FETCH C_DATA_SOURCES INTO DATA_SOURCE_ID_RET;
  EXIT WHEN C_DATA_SOURCES%NOTFOUND;
    query_str:=getHostQuery( DATA_SOURCE_ID_RET);
--SELECT :FIRST_NAME||:LAST_NAME||to_char(:DOB,'yyyy/mm/dd')    
From INPUT_TABLE WHERE     INPUT_ID=:INPUT_ID
using_cl:=getHostUsing(DATA_SOURCE_ID_RET);
--:NEW.FIRST_NAME, :NEW.LAST_NAME, :NEW.DOB, :NEW.INPUT_ID
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query_str  INTO HostId USING using_cl;

  IF INSERTING THEN
    INSERT INTO DETAIL_TABLE
  (
  DETAIL_ID,
  INPUT_ID,
  HOST_ID,
  DATA_SOURCE_ID,
  NOTE,
  DATE_MODIFIED
  ) VALUES
  (
   DETAIL_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
    :NEW.INPUT_ID,
    HostId,
    DATA_SOURCE_ID_RET,
    'Autogenerate Data Source Insert for Insert Input',
    SYSDATE
  );

ELSIF UPDATING THEN



SELECT COUNT(DATA_SOURCE_ID) INTO resultcount FROM DETAIL_TABLE WHERE     
INPUT_ID=:NEW.INPUT_ID AND DATA_SOURCE_ID=DATA_SOURCE_ID_RET;
  IF resultcount>0 THEN


    UPDATE DETAIL_TABLE
    SET
  HOST_ID = HostId,
  NOTE ='Autogenerate Data Source Update for Update Input',
  DATE_MODIFIED =SYSDATE
  WHERE INPUT_ID=:NEW.INPUT_ID
  AND DATA_SOURCE_ID=DATA_SOURCE_ID_RET;


  ELSE
      INSERT INTO DETAIL_TABLE
  (
  DETAIL_ID,
  INPUT_ID,
  HOST_ID,
  DATA_SOURCE_ID,
  NOTE,
  DATE_MODIFIED
  ) VALUES
  (
  DETAIL_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
  :NEW.INPUT_ID,
  HostId,
   DATA_SOURCE_ID_RET,
   'Autogenerate Data Source Insert for Update Input ',

    SYSDATE
  );
END IF;
--end if insert or update inside update

END IF;
--end IF UPDATING
END LOOP;
Close C_DATA_SOURCES;

COMMIT;
END DATA_DETAIL_TRIG;
--end trigger
```